# Which one is the "opt" key in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

I just installed [FoldFunctions](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/73175/foldfunctions) into NetBeans (8.2). The introduction says to

> fold/unfold using cmd+opt+O

I guess that `cmd` is the `Ctrl` key; but if it is, neither the Windows key nor `Alt` or `Shift` are the `opt` key. (Windows 10). Actually I could neither find anything on the net nor any combination of `Ctrl`, `Win`, `Alt`, `Shift` that works.

So: which is the `cmd` and which is the `opt` key?

Comment: I share your confusion regarding the **cmd** and **opt** keys on Windows 10, but I'm also not understanding the purpose of the **FoldFunctions** plugin. In NetBeans there is already functionality for code folding. Position the mouse over your source, right click and select **Code Folds** from the dropdown menu, then select the appropriate folding option from the sub menu. Also see **Tools > Options > Editor > Folding** for configuration. What does **FoldFunctions** do that NetBeans doesn't do already?

Comment: @skomisa "collapse all" is built in; but it collapses all code blocks and comments. I want only the functions to collapse. Thanks for hinting me to the folding options, though.

Comment: Re _"I want only the functions to collapse..."_, what language are you using? (For Java source you can achieve that using **Code Folds > Collapse All Java Code** and **Code Folds > Expand All Java Code**.)

Comment: @skomisa PHP and JS